# How to structure and use an ajax responseText with jQuery to change specific attributes in my page?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm working on building an Image-Gallery on a page. I have several thumbnails which are linked to a bigger image delivered in a lightbox.

I use an ajax call to check if the client is a mobile-phone. If it is, I get an ajax-response (I belief as a string) with the urls for the mobile-versions of this linked images.

Now I want to structure / process the response in the ajax .done() function to change the href-attribut's for every image in my html-page.

Code-snippet of the html-page (There are more images. I just showed 2 for simplicity.):

```
<div class="imageGrid">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class='ajax-1' data-imagelightbox='f' href='/files/image1_big.jpg'>
          <img class='lazyload' 
                sizes='(min-width: 60em) 14vw,
                       (min-width: 30em) 29vw, 43vw'
                data-srcset='/files/image1_thmb_sm.jpg 138w, /files/image1_thmb_lg.jpg 276w' alt=''>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class='ajax-2' data-imagelightbox='f' href='/files/image1_big.jpg'>
          <img class='lazyload' 
                sizes='(min-width: 60em) 14vw,
                       (min-width: 30em) 29vw, 43vw'
                data-srcset='/files/image2_thmb_sm.jpg 138w, /files/image2_thmb_lg.jpg 276w' alt=''>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Code of the ajax-call:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    var screenIs = 'nonMobile';
    if(matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 480px)').matches) {
      screenIs = 'mobile';
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url:  '_your_screen_is.php',
      data: { yourScreen: screenIs}
    })

    .done( function (responseText) {
      // Triggered if response status code is 200 (OK)
      if (responseText !== '') {

        // This code should somehow manage it to structure / process 
        // the responseText so that the right href-attr. is changed


        // I tested this: This would work if I just had one image 
        // with class=ajax and an responseText with one url      

        $('.ajax').attr('href', responseText);

      }
    })
  });
</script>
```

I get this response from the ajax-call. Which I could manipulate - I could for instance delete the whole ".ajax-" part und just having the url. (But I guess this is a string.)

```
.ajax-1: /files/image1_small.jpg,
.ajax-2: /files/image2_small.jpg,
..
```

Thank you for any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to load the images based upon mobile or not, then you should probably change your architecture a bit to where you do not load images until you know if they are on a mobile device.

The way it is structured now, a mobile user would load the non-mobile images (therefore using data) and then the images would swap out, causing more data usage (and probably some not-so-happy mobile users.)

Just setup a container on your page, make your ajax call and have it return a list of images to display based upon mobile or not, then you could fill in the container with the images appropriate for the viewing device (and have happy users.)

If you need a code sample let me know :)

Comment: No, a mobile user would load the appropriate image - as you can see in the html-code. What is changed with the ajax-call on a mobile-client is the LINK to the "lightbox-image", which every user - if mobile or nonMobile - only downloads if he clicks on the thumbnail-image.